# Storing Multiple Logstash configuration files?

Tags: logstash

I know logstash by default says to place them in the logstash default directory according to [Configuring Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html).

However what if you have multiple Logstash configuration files? Doesn't it attempt to load them all on start? or will it only load what you specify. I can't seem to find on the logstash install/configuration tutorials where exactly the best place to keep multiple logstash configuration files at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logstash will load files in that directory in lexical order. You'll see similar ordering on Linux systems in various places. The conventional way to handle load-order is with a prefixed number

```
10-input-syslog.conf
10-input-application.conf
20-filter-syslog.conf
21-filter-application.conf
30-output-elasticsearch.conf
```

Like so. Filters are order-sensitive, so you want to be sure those are numbered right for your usage.